# A word or phrase that can describe what looks bad, ugly, rustic or quite normal but actually has incredibly great internal value?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Is there any word or phrase that can describe someone or something
>   that looks bad, ugly, rustic or quite normal or useless but actually
>   has incredibly great internal value?

```
 ------------------------------------------------
```

> The great qualities are far from easily displayed, maybe  because ordinary
>   people around have no discerning eyes for talent, or because the good
>   things are intentionally concealed.

```
*The ~ in following sample is what I am seeking for.*
```

**People look down upon Peter, for he's constantly wearing shabby clothes. However, few know he's a guy in possession of a large fortune. Peter is ~.**

Comment: How is wealth an "internal value"?

Comment: Just an example. In my view, money-making ability is a great value. You can replace a large fortune with other qualities, like ,   dog training skills,  strong powers of persuasion, etc

Comment: Antique.  And likely you mean intrinsic value, rather than internal value?

Comment: I mean good value, either inherited from previous generations, or something learned the hard way, or bestowed on her by GOD

Comment: Clare, why my question put on hold?? You explain ?

Answer (score 1):

A [diamond in the rough](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diamond%20in%20the%20rough):

> one having exceptional qualities or potential but lacking refinement or polish